# nginx proxy_pass doesn't work with regex

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use nginx as a proxy to route all calls to the other services in a docker network. The rerouting works when I hardcode the subdomains

```
server {
   listen       80;
    server_name sub1.example.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://sub1.example.com;
    }
}
```

But once I start using regex, it starts return 301 like it can't find the host.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^((?<subdomain>.*)\.)(?<domain>[^.]+)\.(?<tld>[^.]+)$;
  location / {
    proxy_pass $scheme://${subdomain}.${domain}.${tld};
  }
}
```

I am getting 502 Bad Gateway (no resolver defined to resolve sub1.example.com). What resolver should I use to keep it all local within docker?

This is my curl response
    curl -v http://sub1.example.com/
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to sub1.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: sub1.example.com
>   User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
>   Accept: */*
>
> ```
> < HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
> < Server: nginx/1.11.6
> < Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2016 21:47:22 GMT
> < Content-Type: text/html
> < Content-Length: 173
> < Connection: keep-alive
> < 
> <html>
> <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
> <body bgcolor="white">
> <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx/1.11.6</center>
> </body>
> </html>
> * Connection #0 to host sub1.example.com left intact
> ```

This is the error log

```
proxy           | 172.19.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2016:21:55:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "curl/7.49.1"
proxy           | 2016/12/13 21:55:23 [error] 13#13: *6 no resolver defined to resolve sub1.example.com, client: 172.19.0.1, server: ~^((?<subdomain>.*)\.)(?<domain>[^.]+)\.(?<tld>[^.]+)$, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "sub1.example.com"
```

Comment: How does the "stop working" show up? What does the log file contain? What is the output on browser?

Comment: Why do you have a `return 301` in there? That will make it return a 301 response and never get to the `proxy_pass`.